# How to run only one fold of cross validation in sklearn?

Tags: scikit-learn

I have he following code to run a 10-fold cross validation in SkLearn:

```
cv = model_selection.KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=0)
scores = model_selection.cross_val_score(MyEstimator(), x_data, y_data, cv=cv, scoring='mean_squared_error') * -1
```

For debugging purposes, while I am trying to make MyEstimator work, I would like to run only one fold of this cross-validation, instead of all 10. Is there an easy way to keep this code but just say to run the first fold and then exit?

I would still like that data is split into 10 parts, but that only one combination of that 10 parts is fitted and scored, instead of 10 combinations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not with `cross_val_score` I suppose. You can set `n_splits` to minimum value of 2, but still that will be 50:50 split of train, test which you may not want.

If you want maintain a 90:10 ration and test other parts of code like `MyEstimator()`, then you can use a workaround.

You can use `KFold.split()` to get the first set of train and test indices and then break the loop after first iteration.

```
cv = model_selection.KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=0)
for train_index, test_index in cv.split(x_data):
    print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
    X_train, X_test = x_data[train_index], x_data[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y_data[train_index], y_data[test_index]
    break
```

Now use this X_train, y_train to train the estimator and X_test, y_test to score it.

Instead of :

```
scores = model_selection.cross_val_score(MyEstimator(), 
                                         x_data, y_data, 
                                         cv=cv, 
                                         scoring='mean_squared_error')
```

Your code becomes:

```
myEstimator_fitted = MyEstimator().fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = myEstimator_fitted.predict(X_test)

from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

# I am appending to a scores list object, because that will be output of cross_val_score.
scores = []
scores.append(mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred))
```

Rest assured, cross_val_score will be doing this only internally, just some enhancements for parallel processing.